# assembly, storing ascii values into a register

Tags: string, assembly

How would I store 8 ascii values into a register or a variable?
For instance I have these values in ascii
30 30 34 20  33 32 32 00

Which would be 004 322

80x86 architecture

Comment: ah, sorry I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mov eax 30303420
mov ebx 33323200
```

or you can do in the data segment

```
var db 30 , 30 ,34 ,20 ,33 ,32 ,32, 00
```

you can use the stack(LIFO) as well:

```
mov eax 30303420
mov ebx 33323200
push ebx
push eax
```

or to one register 8 byte = 8*8 bit = 64 bit:

```
mov rax 3030342033323200h
```

**EDIT:**

```
extern  printf      ; the C function, to be called

SECTION .data       ; Data section, initialized variables

a:  db  30 , 30 ,34 ,20 ,33 ,32 ,32, 00 
fmt:    db "a=%s",'0'


SECTION .text                   ; Code section.

global main     ; the standard gcc entry point
main:               ; the program label for the entry point
push    ebp     ; set up stack frame
mov     ebp,esp

push    a           ; value of variable a
push    fmt
call    printf      ; Call C function
add     esp, 8      ; maybe I missed some bytes here 

mov     esp, ebp    ; takedown stack frame
pop     ebp     ; same as "leave" op

mov eax,0       ;  normal, no error, return value
ret         ; return
```

Comment: if i move 30303420 into  eax, then i get that decimal value back. I want the ASCII value...  which is 004 322.

Comment: if it doesn't work for you let me know I'll edit the answer... check it with printf and link the object file with gcc compiler.

Comment: I tried 30303420h (So I know for sure it's in hex) that doesn't work. If you look on the ascii chart decimal 50 is the same as 32 hex, which is the same as  the character 2. I want the character 2 stored.. but when I use the wtoa macro it just converts it to a decimal.. I don't know how to get it to print the character.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the stack?
Especially if the values are not constants

EDIT:  woops might need some adjustment for 32-bit words  :)

```
; load values
PUSH 30
PUSH 30
PUSH 34
PUSH 20
PUSH 33
PUSH 32
PUSH 32
PUSH 0

; do stuff
; [ESP] = 0  (last value)
; [ESP+7] = 30  (first value)

; restore stack pointer  ("free memory")
SUB ESP, 8
```

Comment: well I need to put all those values into one register / variable... thats what Im confused on